# How can I use a sf::window in a function/method

Tags: c++, function, methods, sfml

I want to make a class that takes a `string`, and gives out the `string` in a box in `sfml`. To make the drawing easier, I made a function that takes a pointer of a `renderwindow` and draws the box with the text(I didn't implement the Box yet)
But when I run it I get an error, that it is not allowed to read this

I already tried to pass the window by reference, but it didn't work, and the result was the same

```
//Textbox.h

class textbox
{
public:
    sf::Text txtinbox;

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow* on)
    {
        on->draw(this->txtinbox);
    }//Error

    textbox(std::string txinbox)
    {

        sf::Font font;
        font.loadFromFile(fontfile);
        sf::Text text(txinbox , font);
        text.setCharacterSize(30);
        text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
        text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
        txtinbox = text;

    }


    ~textbox()
    {}
private:

};
```

Comment: Is it a runtime or compile time error? If it is a compile time error, can you copy paste the whole message?

Comment: As a side note, where is fontfile defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour.

Go on this [site](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a614019e0b5c0ed39a99d32483a51f2c5) and find this sentence:

> It is important to note that the sf::Text instance doesn't copy the
>   font that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it.

and this one

> **never write a function that uses a local** sf::Font instance for
>   creating a text

Now look at your constructor:

```
{
    sf::Font font;                           // LOCAL VARIABLE
    font.loadFromFile(fontfile);
    sf::Text text(txinbox , font);           // GET REFERENCE TO LOCAL
    text.setCharacterSize(30);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    txtinbox = text;
                                             // LOCAL IS DELETED
                                             // txtinbox HAS DANGLING REFERENCE
}
```

so you have to extend lifetime of `font`, for example by making it be data member of your class.

```
class textbox
{
public:
    sf::Text txtinbox;
    sf::Font font;

     textbox(std::string txinbox)
     {
         font.loadFromFile(fontfile);
```

Comment: This problem and a solution could be also a lesson in designing library classes - don't design a class, which requires user to do some magic to make it work and crashes otherwise. `sf::Text` could after all do keep all of its required data in some `shared_ptr` guarded memory.

Comment: This is very popular mistake when using SFML library.
In many places classes take references to other objects.
I don't want to write about library design, 
but it only testifies that users don't read carefully docs before coding.
I can compare this mistake to boost::asio library, and passing
buffer as local variable to async method - async returns immediately, scope ends, buf is destroyed, 
and we have dangling ref. I have seen lots of these mistakens, and I am sure, I will see next ones.